# Фактический размер JFrame не совпадает с задаваемым

Tags: java, jframe

Программирую на Java на MacOS. Разрешение экрана 2560х1600, однако при создании объекта типа JFrame с заданным размером 1200х900 или более объект уже не влезает в экран. С чем это связано и как это решить? С кодом все просто:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(0,0,1200,900);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Более того этот код:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(0,0,3000,3000);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + "x" + frame.getHeight());
```

выводит 1280x773.

Возможно, я неправильно поставил вопрос: Почему JFrame размера 1280х773 полностью заполняет экран?

Comment: А если setSize ?

Comment: Результат тот же самый.

Comment: Может включено какое-то масштабирование? Со шрифтами это точно влияет в Win.

Comment: Я описал весь используемый код. Есть возможность как-то проверить включено ли это масштабирование по умолчанию и выключить его?

Comment: проверить можно. выключить нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у вас используется Retina, то по умолчанию все увеличивается в 2 раза. Иначе все бы выглядело очень маленьким и было бы сложно, что-либо разобрать.

Масштаб задается в классе `sun.awt.CGraphicsDevice`. Вот кусочек из OpenJDK

```
public final class CGraphicsDevice extends GraphicsDevice
        implements DisplayChangedListener {

    private volatile int scale;
```

Проверить можно вот так

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor")
```

Comment: А можно как-либо избавиться от этого масштабирования?

Comment: а зачем именно вам это нужно?

Comment: Пока что мне намного удобнее вручную настраивать все элементы, нежели пользоваться layout'ами.

Comment: Кроме того хотелось бы понимать на каком уровне происходит масштабирование и каким образом этим управлять

Comment: вы понимаете, что на другой платформе у вас все будет по другому? что если вы настроите pixel perfect под одной ОС, то на другой все будет по другому?

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но это не лишает меня природного любопытства и желания понимать инструмент, с которым я работаю, как можно лучше

Comment: я дополнил ответ